# что включается при автозаполнении и как избавится от этого

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsx

пытаюсь разобратся что срабатывает при автозаполнении и как это убрать, не получается, появляется какая то серая полоска и выдиление.

[image: автоподбор]

после нажатия enter появляется еще одна полоска возле закрывающей скобки

[image: полоска рядом с голубой]

и далее какое то выдиление срабатывает вроде, после клика вне или нажатия esc проподает.

[image: выдиление]

вырубил все extensions не помогло, что то встроенное срабатывает.

Comment: Это автокомплит, сниппеты. Серая область обозначает, что при табе вы переместитесь туда.

Comment: @OliverPatterson как то избавится мануально, например тут мне это ну вообще не надо.